# Uploading to Azure blob storage using Javascript fails?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am following this tutorial to upload a video to blob storage - https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html#step1

I have done all of them including enabling CORS. 
Currently I have set CORS to enable * for max period.

But i am still getting

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
:9000/#/:1 Failed to load https://XXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/3d7959e4-a48d-447b-a919-

    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

I had it working two days ago, but it just suddenly stopped working.

Here is my javascript on how I am calling.

```
var blobUri = 'https://XXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/';
            var sastoken = 'XXXXXX';
            var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sastoken);

            var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
            blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;

            var customediaid = mediaid;

            //Guid
            //Wrong guid here- create a proper one
            var customazureid = guid + ".mp4";

            var finishedOrError = false;
            var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile(
                customediaid,
                customazureid,
                file,
                { blockSize: customBlockSize },
                function (error, result, response) {
                    finishedOrError = true;
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Failed look console');
                    } else {
                      alert('Success - Check folder named -' + mediaid + "with filename - " + customazureid + '.mp4');
                      UpdateDatabase(mediaid, azuremediaid);

                    }

                }
            );
```

Have my cors enabled like this for the storage account.

```
ALLOWED ORIGINS ALLOWED METHODS ALLOWED HEADERS EXPOSED HEADERS MAX AGE
* GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS,MERGE,DELETE * * 2147483647
```

Also in the tutorial website, you can list all the containers using SAS token and storage account. That also works when I add in those fields. It just wont work in my site.

Edit

Not sure if this helps, but here is how the request looks like by using the postman tool to capture them.

https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/02b8be3e-22b7-41fc-a1d3-831153f8de90/97d603e4-767d-ddc2-169a-379db3af7419.mp4?comp=block&blockid=Njc4YTA4Nz

```
Request Headers
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type,x-ms-client-request-id,x-ms-date,x-ms-version
    Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
    Connection:keep-alive
    DNT:1
    Host:XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net
    Origin:http://localhost:9000
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
```

Respone I get is -

```
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Comment: Your CORS settings look OK to me. `400` error usually means there's a user error. Will it be possible for you to edit your question and include the request parameters sent and the detailed response received.

Comment: @GauravMantri I added the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I just reused your code with my azure blob storage as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://brucchstorage.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/azurestoragejs-0.2.8-preview/azure-storage.blob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadfile() {
        var blobUri = 'https://brucchstorage.blob.core.windows.net';
        var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, 'st=2018-04-04T21%3A41%3A00Z&se=2018-04-05T21%3A41%3A00Z&sp=rw&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=D1HX40pFCONuWGKTCKCYXyWvbwuErrog6yTfk%2FZBQ1A%3D');

        // If one file has been selected in the HTML file input element
        var file = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];

        var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
        blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;

        var finishedOrError = false;
        var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('images', file.name, file, { blockSize: customBlockSize }, function (error, result, response) {
            finishedOrError = true;
            if (error) {
                // Upload blob failed
                alert("error:" + error);
            } else {
                // Upload successfully
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

If I do not configure the CORS for my blob storage, I would retrieve the following error:

[image]

Then, I used Azure Storage Explorer to set the CORS as follows:

[image]

**TEST:**

[image]

Moreover, I would recommend you open a new incognito window to narrow down this issue.